# How to resolve Gemfile.lock contains merge conflicts (running `git checkout HEAD -- Gemfile.lock` does not work)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems, bundler

I got an error message after I ran `bundle install` in my ruby on rails app, the error message was:

```
Your Gemfile.lock contains merge conflicts.
Run `git checkout HEAD -- Gemfile.lock` first to get a clean lock.
```

So I tried `git checkout HEAD -- Gemfile.lock` in the same terminal, however, it does not change anything. The Gemfile.lock contains merge conflicts error still shows up when I tried to bundle.

I also tried `git checkout Gemfile.lock`, which returned  "Updated 0 paths from the index", and the problem persists.

My Gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.3.1'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 1.1'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'
# allow video upload
# gem 'carrierwave', '~> 2.0'

# gemfile to solve mimemagic problem
gem 'mimemagic', github: 'mimemagicrb/mimemagic', ref: '01f92d86d15d85cfd0f20dabd025dcbd36a8a60f'

# Carrierwave
gem 'carrierwave-video'
gem 'carrierwave-video-thumbnailer'
gem 'carrierwave_backgrounder'
gem 'streamio-ffmpeg'
gem 'ffmpeg'


# Delayed job used by carrierwave_backgrounder
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'

# Figaro parses a Git-ignored YAML file in your application and loads its values into ENV
# to securely configure Rails applications
gem "figaro"

# for carrierwave to be able to communicate with Amazon S3
gem "fog-aws"

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false

gem 'pry-byebug'
gem 'better_errors'
gem 'awesome_print'
# populate database with fake data for demo purpose
gem 'faker'
# Hirb.enable displays nice database schema and entries in ASCII table
gem 'hirb'
# gem 'mimemagic', github: 'mimemagicrb/mimemagic', ref: '01f92d86d15d85cfd0f20dabd025dcbd36a8a60f'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  # Display performance information such as SQL time and flame graphs for each request in your browser.
  # Can be configured to work on production as well see: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/blob/master/README.md
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
# Uncomment the following line if you're running Rails
# on a native Windows system:
# gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]


#Add Bootstrap
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.4.1'

#Add jekyll -- a layout tool
gem "jekyll"

group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "jekyll-feed"
  gem "jekyll-seo-tag"
end
```

Part of my Gemlock that looks suspicious of causing this problem

```
accept current change | accept incoming change | accept both changes | compare changes
<<<<<<< HEAD
    ffmpeg (0.2.5)
=======
    figaro (1.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14.0, < 2)
    fog-aws (3.10.0)
      fog-core (~> 2.1)
      fog-json (~> 1.1)
      fog-xml (~> 0.1)
      ipaddress (~> 0.8)
    fog-core (2.2.3)
      builder
      excon (~> 0.71)
      formatador (~> 0.2)
      mime-types
    fog-json (1.2.0)
      fog-core
      multi_json (~> 1.10)
    fog-xml (0.1.3)
      fog-core
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.11, < 2.0.0)
    formatador (0.2.5)
>>>>>>> aws
```

What does the <<< HEAD  and  >>>> aws mean? should I accept the current change or the incoming change?

Any ideas or thoughts would help, thank you in advance!

Comment: If you would like to keep both lines, then the conflict markers can be removed manually. Then finish the merge commit (`git commit`)

Comment: Dealing with merge conflicts is a standard thing all Git users have to go through. Learn to do it; it's not *that* hard, in most cases. What you're running into is the leavings of someone else who *didn't* learn to do it, and committed the conflicted file. You can blame the other guy, but you still have to fix it yourself.

Comment: To evolutionxbox, Thank you!

Comment: To torek, thanks for the advice, definitely gonna learn more about git.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

1. go to master branch
2. run

   git reset --hard origin/master
3. run bundle install